# Using a LINQ Where query to get only some of the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings

Tags: c#, linq, connection-string, configurationmanager

My goal is to use a LINQ `Where` query on the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` collection in a console application (assume a fresh .NET 4.5 console application with a System.Configuration  reference added, and a correspodning `using` statement).

I started with this, **which does *not* work**:

```
var relevantSettings =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Where(s => s.Name.StartsWith("Xyz"));
```

It tells me that:

> The type arguments for method '`IEnumerable<TSource> System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource(this IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,bool>)`' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the arguments explicitly.

This caught me off guard, so I tried this to check my sanity, but **this does *not* work** either:

```
foreach (var settingsin ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    if (settings.Name.StartsWith("Xyz")) Console.WriteLine("Found one!");
}
```

It complains *not* about the `foreach` statement, but about the `.Name` bit, with the error:

> Could not resolve symbol 'Name'

I understand that there's probably something preventing the compiler from inferring the `var`'s type, to double check I tried this **which *does* work**:

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings settings in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    if (connectionString.Name.StartsWith("Xyz")) Console.WriteLine("Found one!");
}
```

However, that doesn't help me very much, except for solving my immediate problem. I want to *understand* what is going on here.

All I wanted to do is use a simple LINQ `Where` statement to get a subset of the connection strings in my app.config. Why is the compiler preventing me from doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## TL;DR Version

You need to do a `.Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>()` to make this work.

## Details

Well, if you dig even a little deeper, you can get the compiler to tell you even more:

```
Func<ConnectionStringSettings, bool> StartsWithXyz = c => c.Name.StartsWith("Xyz");
var relevantSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Where(StartsWithXyz);
```

This is tells you:

> Cannot convert instance argument type '`System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings>`'

Driving up the inheritance tree of the `ConnectionStringSettings` property you can finally see the culprit, which makes a lot of sense: **that property is of the *non* generic `IEnumerable` type**.

This in fact makes the question a rather elaborate duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776397/419956), as the solution lies in casting the non-generic property to a generic list, so that LINQ and the compiler may do their magic. For this particular scenario, **the following *does* work**:

```
var relevantSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                                           .Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>()
                                           .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("Xyz"));
```

Enjoy!

Comment: +1 Not only a duplicate of [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/776397/419956) but also of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414317/system-data-datarowcollection-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-tolist-and-no) i've answered 9 hours ago.  Basically the reason for this is that those classes are older than generics in C#.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there could be more duplicates, once you *do* understand the problem it's gonna be easy to spot them. I had used the "Ask Question" feature as a rubber duck, helping me find my answer. I figured my text *might help others* searching for this specific instance of this problem, and since there didn't seem to be one about `ConnectionStrings` yet so I posted it anyways.

Comment: It  was not meant as  criticism.  In this case it's not clear why they didn't let [the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) implement `IEnumerable<ConnectionStringSettings>` since  it's also from .NET 2.0 where generics were introduced. I guess that they weren't finished at the time of birth of that class,

Comment: Ah, point taken! (I had guessed as much from the "+1", but reading back my comment I guess I implied that I felt criticism). Thank you for your feedback.