# Multiple Groups of ConnectionStrings in App Config

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config

Using `ConnectionStrings` in `App.config`, is it possible to have multiple groups/sections of connectionstrings? Some way to delineate between one set of connections and another. Either something like;

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="ConA" connectionString="Data Source=..."
        <add name="ConB" connectionString="Data Source=..."
    </connectionStrings>
    <otherConnectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="ConC" connectionString="Data Source=..."
        <add name="ConD" connectionString="Data Source=..."
    </otherConnectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

OR

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="ConA" Group="1" connectionString="Data Source=..."
        <add name="ConB" Group="1" connectionString="Data Source=..."
        <add name="ConC" Group="2" connectionString="Data Source=..."
        <add name="ConD" Group="2" connectionString="Data Source=..."
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I know there are `<configSections>` which you can use to split up the config file, but I want to use `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;` to access the connectionStrings if possible.

**NEED**

I have two dropdown boxes. One is populated with a list of possible connectionStrings. Selecting an option will populate the second dropdown with a sublist of the remaining connectionStrings based on the option selected in dropdown 1. How would you cleanly populate both? Perhaps I'll just need to create connectionStringName lists in code for each group of connections I could potentially need and have all my connections in a the single section in my config?

Comment: No, you would need to create a custom config section. An alternative might be to include the group in the name (prefix or sufix) with some delimiter character. Your code could then handle the grouping.

Comment: separated configsection is the way to go here, buddy. "otherConnectionStrings" cannot be used for web config has a strict syntax meanwhile configsection doesn

Comment: different files would work I guess

Comment: This seems like an XY problem - why would you even want to do this?

Comment: @DavidG Let's say you have two dropdown boxes. One is populated with a list of possible connectionStrings, the other with a sublist of the remaining connectionStrings based on the option selected in dropdown 1. How would you cleanly populate both? I guess I'll just need to create connectionStringName lists in code for each group of connections I could potentially need.

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be storing this data in the app config file then, why not keep it in a separate XML or JSON file? That way you can easily serialise it to a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` for example.

Comment: @DavidG Hmm that might make the most sense actually.

Comment: if you want to refer to the connection strings from somewhere else (eg drop down), why not leave the connection strings as-is in the `connectionStrings` section, and then add some custom app settings or something where you define groups and refer to connectionStrings by their name?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. It seems having separate `connectionStrings` sections isn't possible. In order to hold onto that functionality for all my connections I conceded to having them all together but prefixing their names based on the grouping (as per @Igor's suggestion), then in code using Linq to select only the connections I needed.

Note: In order to use Linq on `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection` you need to `.Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>()` as per; https://stackoverflow.com/a/26419656/1365650